# How to fix disproportional scaling across multiple images at the same time in InDesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, resize, indesign-scripting

In InDesign CS6, you have to directly select an image and scale up or down after clicking the "constrain proportions" chain-link button in order to revert the proportions back to normal.  When selecting multiple images at the same time, this trick does not work.  To save time, I'd like to fix multiple disproportional images all at once.  Could this be done by writing a script?  Is there an easier way?

Thanks!
-JD

Comment: Don't scale multiple images. Indesign CS4 did not suffer from this issue.. they broke things at CS5 and Adobe *thinks* it's better.

Comment: Unfortunately, my current job leaves me no choice but to scale multiple images.  Hehe, Adobe seems to think a lot of things lately, don't they?

Comment: Have you already try with creating an object style?
Can you provide an example so I can try to help you?

Comment: Hi @Stefano! Welcome to GD.SE. We follow a strict Q&A format (as opposed to a forum format), so I converted your post into a comment because it doesn't answer the question. You can always comment on your own posts, and commenting anywhere is unlocked at 50 reputation. You can visit our [help] to read more about how the site works. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it's been a while since I posted this question but I figured I would let everyone know what my solution was.  The truth is, there is no way for InDesign CS6 to reset the proportions of stretched images.  The only method is to directly select the graphic, then scale up or down with the proportions locked, then they will match.

BUT

I learned a thing or two about scripting since my last visit, so just add this little snippet to your scripts folder and you can select a whole bunch of images and run this script to reset all their proportions at the same time.

```
//Resets each selected image to its original proportions, one at a time.

function runAll(){
    //loops through each selected item.
    for(loop = 0; loop < app.selection.length; loop++){
        var sel = loop;

        //makes sure the current item has graphics.
        if (app.selection[sel].allGraphics.length > 0) {

            //loops through all graphics contained by each selected item.
            for(img = 0; img < app.selection[sel].allGraphics.length; img++){
                var cuts = app.selection[sel].allGraphics[img];

                //checks if the image is stretched vertically or horizontally, then unstretches it
                if (cuts.horizontalScale > cuts.verticalScale){
                    cuts.horizontalScale = cuts.verticalScale;
                }else{
                    cuts.verticalScale = cuts.horizontalScale;
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}

//make all actions into a single undo step
if (parseFloat(app.version) < 6)
    runAll();
else
    app.doScript(
        runAll,
        ScriptLanguage.JAVASCRIPT,
        undefined,
        UndoModes.ENTIRE_SCRIPT,
        "Make Images Proportional"
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Does selecting all of the images and pressing ctrl+alt+shift+C (cmd+opt+shift+c) do the trick? That command will fill the frame, locking the original image proportions. At that point, the extra image will extend (hidden) outside the frame. To remedy that, ctrl+alt+c (cmd+opt+c) will extend the frame to the image's full size.

Comment: No sir, it does not work.  That will fill the frame, locking the CURRENT proportions.  Thank you for the response!

Comment: No problem, but perhaps I misinterpreted your problem. At what point are your images' proportions being compromised? If I were resizing multiple images simultaneously while constraining proportions, I would tick the option to do so, then either enter the size or drag the frames diagonally and fit the content to the frame. If the proportions were already messed up, I would fill the frame proportionally, recalling the original proportions. What am I missing?

Comment: For my job, I sometimes have to add an item to a grocery sale ad page.  In order to do this, I select all the items in the row and scale them horizontally.  Of course, this is when things distort.  Due to vertical size constraints, proportionally scaling is not an option, however I must fix distorted images.  To make the process faster, it would be nice to select all images in the row and fix them all at once, but that would seem impossible.  Instead, I'm stuck directly selecting each individual image, and scaling up or down once with proportions locked.